# Current Customer List?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, devkit, customer-account-data-api

I am testing the AggCat service and trying to put together a prototype.  I'm using the .Net DevKit and have properly gotten through all the authentication issues including MFA.

Unfortunately, I'm now getting a "Forbidden" as it says I've hit a max-accounts error.  I'm thinking what has actually happened is that there are orphan users/customers in my profile that I need to purge (probably from failed tests).

How can I get a list of defined customer entities in my account?  I can only create the AggCat service using a customer id and once I've done that there's no way I can find to list all customers.

Answer (score 1):

While in development, if you are doing a discoverAndAddAccounts call for a financial institution where you have more than 10 accounts, or if the result of the call would put you over the 10 account limit, you will receive this error.  For instance, if I have 2 accounts in the system and do a discoverAndAddAccounts at a FI where I have 9 accounts, the system will recognize that and stop you from adding the additional 9 accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You should be keeping track of the customers you have created. Please submit a support ticket via appcenter and we will be able to get you a listing.

Comment: Great, I will.  As I was testing, I'm assuming something got created that I didn't intend-- at least that's what I gather based on my error.